# Filling fields with defaults when value is None

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql, ponyorm

I encountered a problem with fields, which may have None (or null) values. Regardless how I define the field, Pony either draws an error or it just writes null values.

Attempt 1 (output when running with `db.set_sql_debug(True)`):

```
# phone = orm.Required(str, default='not available')
#
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `uid` VARCHAR(13) PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `archived` BOOLEAN
)
```

Result: `ValueError: Attribute Contacts.phone is required`

Attempt 2:

```
# phone = orm.Optional(str, default='not available')
#
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `uid` VARCHAR(13) PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `archived` BOOLEAN
)
```

Result for 2nd try: `ValueError: Attribute Contacts.phone cannot be set to None`

Attempt 3:
Try #3 will work, but the null values in the database are really NULL values, not empty strings [according the documentation](https://docs.ponyorm.org/api_reference.html?highlight=nullable#optional-string-attributes) :

```
# phone = orm.Optional(str, nullable=True, default='not available')
#
CREATE TABLE `edis_itmap_tbl_contacts` (
  `uid` VARCHAR(13) PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(255),
  `archived` BOOLEAN
)
```

| uid | name | email | phone | archived |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39VSPJVSS2Z42 | Some Name | some@email.com | NULL | 0 |

So, my findings for the moment:

- regardless what I define for default, it is not used at all
- Optional fields are not really optional
- None is stored as NULL and not as empty string

Environment:

- Pony 0.7.14
- PyMySQL 1.0.2
- Python 3.8.8
- MariaDB 10.3
- Debian 10

Any hints what I do wrong here? I used PonyORM with PostgreSQL in a previous project, where such definitions worked perfectly.

Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Below is the `Required` class in pony, if you look closer at line 3 in the `validate` method, you'll see that pony checks if the `sql_default` attribute has been set for the field or not, and not the `default` attribute.

For more details, you can [read the docs](https://docs.ponyorm.org/api_reference.html#cmdoption-arg-default) about the `default` attribute and its behavior.

```py
class Required(Attribute):
    __slots__ = []
    def validate(attr, val, obj=None, entity=None, from_db=False):
        val = Attribute.validate(attr, val, obj, entity, from_db)
        if val == '' or (val is None and not (attr.auto or attr.is_volatile or attr.sql_default)):
            if not from_db:
                throw(ValueError, 'Attribute %s is required' % (
                      attr if obj is None or obj._status_ is None else '%r.%s' % (obj, attr.name)))
            else:
                warnings.warn('Database contains %s for required attribute %s'
                              % ('NULL' if val is None else 'empty string', attr),
                              DatabaseContainsIncorrectEmptyValue)
        return val
```